# SQLite3 database conditional summing

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am looking to order a list of keys based on the number of orders placed from a database containing order requests. Basically, on table, call it orders(o_partkey, o_returnflag) I am trying to get the total number of returns for each order. I have tried many variations of the following snippet with the goal schema returnlist(partkey, numreturns):

```
select O.o_partkey as partkey,
    count(case when O.o_returnflag = 'R' then 1 else 0 end) as numreturns
from orders O
orderby quantity_returned desc;
```

I am very new to SQLite and am just jumping into the basics. This is an adjustment of a homework question (the actual question is more complex) but I have simplified down the issue I am having.

Comment: How is an order identified? A part is not an order, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a derived table subquery with `SUM()` as the aggregate function:

```
SELECT dT.partkey, dT.numreturns
FROM
   (SELECT O.o_partkey as partkey,
       SUM(CASE WHEN O.o_returnflag = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as numreturns       
    FROM [ORDER] O
    GROUP BY O.o_partkey) AS dT
ORDER BY dT.numreturns DESC;
```

Be sure to bracket name of table as `[ORDER]` is an [SQLite key word](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that COUNT counts *rows*, so it counts both `0` and `1` values.

You are not interested in any other rows, so you can just filter out the returns with WHERE:

```
SELECT o_partkey AS partkey,
       COUNT(*) AS numreturns
FROM orders
WHERE o_returnflag = 'R'
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```